# My cron job only runs once, I would like it to run every minute

Tags: javascript, node.js, cron, discord, discord.js

I tried searching for solutions or any info about using cron with discord js but the search came up pretty fruitless. I am still very inexperienced, I hope you can be patient with me :p

```
const { mudaeon, mudaeoff} = require('./mudaetime.json')
const cron  = require('cron');

module.exports = {
    name: 'mudaetime',
    description: '...',
    async execute(message, args){
        if(mudaeon){
            const channel = message.client.channels.cache.get('*id*')
            let scheduledMessage = new cron.CronJob("*/1 * * * *", () => {
                scheduledMessage.start()},
                message.react('✅'),
                channel.send("check $tu ! <@&*id*>"))
        } else(mudaeoff);{
            let scheduledMessage = new cron.CronJob("*/1 * * * *")
            scheduledMessage.stop();
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: Your cron time is wrong, see this `https://crontab.guru/every-1-minute`, you want `* * * * *`, not `*/1 * * * *`

Comment: Use `* * * * *`

Comment: i've tried with `* * * * *` too, they didn't work

Comment: 1. Make sure your code runs fine when just printing out some log message `console.log()`. It looks weird to me that you are telling the `scheduledMessage` to start the `CronJob` inside the `CronJob`. Looks like this is never executed because the `Cronjob` wasn't executed in the first place. 2. My knowledge with JavaScript is too insufficient but is your used `CronJob` `async` compatible? You are missing `await` statements for your `message.react` and `channel.send`. 3. Again my JavaScript knowledge is little but it looks to me you also have a scope problem. I might be wrong here though.

Comment: `} else(mudaeoff);{` has a rogue `;` also `require` uses a cache, so mudaeon and mudaeoff wont update between invocations.. edit: wait a sec it should be `} else if (mudaeoff)`

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/cron The code is all over the place. You are defining in the passed function of `cron.Cronjob` what is going to be executed. With the `cron.Cronjob` object instance you are telling it when to `.start()` and `.stop()`. You are also redefining your `cron.Cronjob` object instance. First priority is to get a basic example running. Then make it work with `discord.js` but again I'm not sure if it is async compatible.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you never actually started your cronJob. Looking through the Cron docs(https://www.npmjs.com/package/cron#usage-basic-cron-usage), you need to start your Cron job for it to execute the code. The second parameter when initializing a cron job is the function to be executed. This function will only execute after you call the job.

Try this:

```
const cron = require('cron');

module.exports = {
    name: 'mudaetime',
    description: '...',
    async execute(message, args) {
        if (mudaeon) {
            const channel = message.client.channels.cache.get('*id*');
            let scheduledMessage = new cron.CronJob(
                '*/1 * * * *',
                () => {
          message.react('✅'); 
          channel.send('check $tu ! <@&*id*>');
                },
                
      );
      scheduledMessage.start();
        } else mudaeoff;
        {
            let scheduledMessage = new cron.CronJob('*/1 * * * *');
            scheduledMessage.stop();
        }
    },
};
```

Hope this fixes your problem!

Comment: thank you for this! I'll give this a go and see what I can learn from it :D

Answer (score 0):

So i ended up taking up Tin Nyugen's advice and got a basic example running, turns out this was a lot simpler than I was making it out to be:

```
    const cron = require('node-cron');


module.exports = {
    name: 'mudaestart',
    description: '...',
    execute(message, args){
        message.react('✅')
        cron.schedule('* * * * *', () => {
            message.channel.send('check $tu !! <@&id>')
        })
    }
}
```

I switched to node-cron :p I'm not sure this is the best way to write this code but I'm just so happy it works and I've learnt a lot just trying to code this command!